# Ruby/JRuby: self.foo() not the same as foo() when inheriting from Delegator

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm writing an application which I want to keep compatible with Ruby version from 1.9.3 up to current, and should run under MRI Ruby and JRuby. This was no real problem so far until I decided to use the `Delegator` class from the standard library. Although I used the docs for the 1.9.3 Ruby version when writing my code, my program worked with i.e. Ruby 2.3 or JRuby 9.x, but not with JRuby 1.7 (which corresponds to the Ruby 1.9.3 code base. Now I could easily dispose with this by attributing this to a bug in the older Ruby code; however, the details of the behaviour are in a way that I can't understand how a simple bug could account for this. Maybe I'm using the Delegator class in a wrong way, and it just *happens* to work by chance in newer Ruby versions. Here is a fairly minimal example which shows the behaviour:

```
require 'delegate'

class DelegFile < Delegator

  def initialize(filename)
    @fp = File.new(filename, "w:UTF-8", {universal_newline: true})
    super(@fp)
  end

  def out_1
    self.puts('yyyy1111')
  end

  def out_2
    puts('yyyy2222') # This causes trouble
  end

  def __getobj__
    @fp
  end

  def __setobj__(obj)
    @fp = obj
  end

end

# Using the class
df = DelegFile.new("x.bak")
df.puts('xxxx')
df.out_1
df.out_2 # Writes to STDOUT!
df.puts('yyyy')
df.close
```

An object of class DelegFile basically behaves like a File, with two methods added and a specifically tailored constructor. Of course, one could here equally well, for instance, using inheritance for File, but I want to demonstrate the problem when using `Delegator`:

When I run this program on new Ruby/JRuby versions, all *puts* statements write their output to the file. When running it on old Ruby versions (1.9.3,...), the string *yyyy2222* is written to STDOUT, while everything else ends up in the file.

With other words,

```
 puts
```

inside my class does not delegate, but invokes `Kernel#puts`, while

```
self.puts
```

delegates.

I would have expected, that a method call `foo()` is equivalent to `self.foo()`, unless, of course, *foo* is a private method. Now, why can I possibly see a different behaviour between `puts` and `self.puts`?

Comment: Sounds like a regression. They should be equivalent.